# How to remove `NA` from set of vectors

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have `n`-size vectors `w1`, `w2`, `w3`. I need to remove `NA` from each column of corresponded elements.
For `6`-size vectors:

```
w1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  2,  1) 
w2 <- c(NA, NA,  4,  3, NA, NA)
w3 <- c(6,  5, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

expected result is  `(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)`

I save vectors in `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(w1, w2, w3)
remove <- c("NA")
```

And then try to remove `NA` row-by-row

```
w <- c()
k <- nrow(df)

for(i in 1:k)
{
w <- c(w, df[i,] [! df[i,] %in% remove])
}

df <- data.frame(df, w=unlist(w))
```

**My result is in df$w:**

```
df
  w1 w2 w3 w
1 NA NA  6 6
2 NA NA  5 5
3 NA  4 NA 4
4 NA  3 NA 3
5  2 NA NA 2
6  1 NA NA 1
```

**Question.** Could someone guide me how to rewrite code in the vector form without `for-loop`?

Comment: `rowSums(df, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Use `is.na`. Look here for examples http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmax/pmin` if there is only a single non-NA element for each corresponding element in the `vector`s

```
pmax(w1, w2, w3, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 6 5 4 3 2 1
```